# Does becoming Charmed disrupt Concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, concentration

If a spell caster, while concentrating on a spell, becomes charmed, does he/she lose concentration automatically? Or does he/she have to make a concentration check? Or is concentration not affected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By RAW, being charmed does not end concentration; it isn't listed in the things-that-break-concentration in PHB 203.

However, it would still be up to the DM, if he so rules, that a check would be needed, as PHB 204 states:

> The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you’re on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.

Being *charmed* isn't an *environmental* effect, per se, but in keeping with 5e's spirit of rulings-over-rules, I think leaving it up to the DM would be how it was intended.

---

### OK, daze, but that isn't really helpful if I'm the DM

Consider the spell being concentrated on and the charmer in question. If the spell is detrimental to the charmer, a *charmed* person would likely end the spell as

> You can end concentration at any time (no action required). (PHB 203)

because, according to the rules on being *charmed* in PHB 290:

> A charmed creature can't attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects

Anything other than that, a check or ending concentration outright would be totally within the rules.

Answer (score 6):

### Not unless the DM rules otherwise

The SRD *(v5.1, p.102)* is pretty clear on laying out the circumstances that break concentration, and becoming charmed is not on the list:

> The following factors can break concentration:
>
> - Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once.
> - Taking damage. Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an arrow and a dragon’s breath, you make a separate saving throw for each source of damage.
> - Being incapacitated or killed. You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated or if you die.

However, even beyond the usual "the DM can rule anything," there's an escape hatch there for them (though the suggestion is at least that it requires a check, not immediately ending concentration):

> The GM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you’re on a storm tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.

That being said, it's notable that designers have said (I'm looking for a citation here) that concentration is one of the areas of the rules that they recommend not messing with when making house rules/variants because a lot of game balance rests on it.

Possibly a tangential question that's worth asking as well is whether it's possible to continue concentration when you're currently concentrating on a spell which harms the creature who charmed you *(v5.1, p. 358)*:

> #### Charmed
>
> - A charmed creature can’t attack the charmer or target the charmer with harmful abilities or magical effects.
> - The charmer has advantage on any ability check to interact socially with the creature.

Answer (score 1):

It is not directly listed that being charmed causes one to lose concentration. So must the charmed break concentration,? no... simply put.

Would that creature  maintain concentration? Thatis completely circumstantial.

They must follow the rules for charmed in that they won't knowingly harm the charmer. Beyond that it's completely open.

One merely needs to examine what the charmed condition means.  They treat the charmer as a friend or good acquaintance.

This does not give them any affinity towards the charmers party nor negate any previous affinities towards any of the charm person's friends.

I..E. it does not guarantee that the charmed person will release a harmful spell against a member of your party nor does it mean they will all of a sudden help you against their own.  They only thing you can bank on is them not harming you. I know this veers away from the specific question of charm vs. Concentration... instead consider this a parallel behind a dms mindset in whether they can choose to or not to.

Anything you get him to do or not do outside of this falls into standard roleplay and may be subject to the appropriate skill checcks.

For example, let's not forget, there's a big difference between friendly acquaintance and say a lover. If you were combat charm without dominate is not going to make him immediately attack his lover... that's ludicrous.  You'd have to convince him some way. He'd probably try to stop both of you at first.

In the end he may have to take sides if say his lovers on deaths door.  One of the few situational moments where doing what makes sense may trump the magic behind charm itself and RAW of charm.    But that's a dm decision. In my games conflict with someone more affectionate than the friendly acquaintance can and will provide another saving throw.

Charm is one of the most difficult spells to adjudicate. Plus for great question.